# Difference container and user profile

Tags: docker, operating-systems, user-profiles

EDIT: I want to create a "portable user profile" or "portable set of gui apps with their custom files and settings".

I don't understand the difference between having a separate user profile on Windows and running a container SINCE YOU CAN RUN ANY .EXE FROM ANOTHER USER BY RIGHT CLICKING ON IT WITH NECESSARY PRIVILEGES.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So would a better question be "What is the purpose of Docker?" ? That sounds like what you are asking.

Comment: I want to create a "portable user profile" or "portable set of gui apps with their custom files and settings"

Comment: The apps will need to support this, or the OS will. What OS? Many apps have config files and you could create a collection of a portable apps. The portable profile thing is going to be the more difficult part, but once again, we need to know which OS.